# How to validate row selection in react ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

```
<div style={containerStyle} className="ag-theme-material">
  <AgGridReact
    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
    rowSelection={this.state.rowSelection}
    onSelectionChanged={this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this)}
    onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
    groupSelectsChildren={true}
    suppressRowClickSelection={true}
    rowData={[{payment_date: 'jan', status: '100'}, {payment_date: 'feb', status: '200'}, {payment_date: 'mar', status: '300'}]}
  >
  </AgGridReact>
</div>

onSelectionChanged() {
  var selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();            
  let paymentsrequest = [];

  selectedRows.forEach(function(selectedRow, index) {
    let paymentslistobject = {
      'payment_date': selectedRow["payment_date"],
      'status': selectedRow["status"]
    };
    paymentsrequest.push(paymentslistobject);
  });

  this.setState({
    paymentsrequest
  });
}

this.state = {
  rowSelection: "multiple",
  columnDefs: [
  {
    headerName: "Amount",
    field: "status",
    width: 250
  },{
    headerName: "Pay",
    field: "",
    checkboxSelection: true,
    width: 100
  },{
    headerName: 'Payment Date',
    field: 'payment_date',
    width: 250
  },
  ],
}
```

I am using react ag-grid component, I am using `checkboxSelection` for one of the column using `checkboxSelection: true`

I have check boxs for all the rows but once first row is checked only then he should be able to check second row till the time we should disable the checkboxes untill he checks first checkbox.

How to validate in `columDefs` as i was using `checkboxSelection: true`, How can I validate.

I checked all the documents for this but I didnot found any document

Comment: Is this possible with this, or any other alternate way to do.

Comment: its possible, but would require to create custom renderer with own logic of `selection`